Strange assertion in WinAPI when calling fclose on console handle
I am developing C++ shared library that is embedded as a plugin into my application using the Unity engine, and, possibly, into Qt applications (also developed by my company).
I want to allocate console for my application (to see debug output of my library). I also want the console to be released when the plugin is unloaded. So I tried to write a simple wrapper for WinAPI functions, encapsulating them into RAII class.
header.h:
#pragma once

#include <array>
#include <cstdint>
#include <winapi20/detail/export.h>
#include <winapi20/detail/cvt.h>
#include <winapi20/detail/exception.h>
#include <winapi20/wrappers/pid.h>

namespace winapi
{
  class WINAPI20_EXPORT ConsoleHost
  {
   public:
    enum class Mode
    {
      Stdout = 1 << 0,
      Stderr = 1 << 1,
      Stdin  = 1 << 2,
      All    = Stdout | Stderr | Stdin
    };

    explicit ConsoleHost(Mode mode) noexcept(false);
    ~ConsoleHost() noexcept;

    ConsoleHost(ConsoleHost const&) = delete;
    ConsoleHost& operator=(ConsoleHost const&) = delete;
    ConsoleHost(ConsoleHost&&) = delete;
    ConsoleHost& operator=(ConsoleHost&&) = delete;

    /// some other unrelated functions....

   public:
    static auto free() noexcept -> void;

   private:
    bool m_attached;
    std::array<std::FILE*, 3> m_handles;
    std::array<void*, 3> m_original_handles;
  };
} // namespace winapi

source.cc:
#include <winapi20/impl/consoleapi_impl.h>

#if defined(_MSC_VER)
# if defined(__amd64__) || defined(__amd64) || defined(__x86_64__) || defined(__x86_64) || defined(_M_X64) || defined(_M_AMD64)
#   define _AMD64_
# elif defined(i386) || defined(__i386) || defined(__i386__) || defined(__i386__) || defined(_M_IX86)
#   define _X86_
# elif defined(__arm__) || defined(_M_ARM) || defined(_M_ARMT)
#   define _ARM_
# endif
# include <consoleapi.h>
#endif // _MSC_VER

#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <winapi20/impl/errhandlingapi_impl.h>
#include <winapi20/detail/exception.h>
#include <winapi20/detail/windows_headers.h>

using std::array;
using std::string;
using std::string_view;
using std::wstring;

namespace {
  auto try_alloc() noexcept(false) -> void {
    if(not AllocConsole())
      throw winapi::windows_exception(winapi::last_error_string());
  }

  auto try_free() noexcept -> bool {
    if(not ::FreeConsole())
      return false;
    return true;
  }

  auto get_handles() noexcept(false) -> array<void*, 3> {
    auto handles = array<void*, 3>();
    handles[0] = reinterpret_cast<void*>(::GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE));
    handles[1] = reinterpret_cast<void*>(::GetStdHandle(STD_ERROR_HANDLE));
    handles[2] = reinterpret_cast<void*>(::GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE));
    return handles;
  }

  auto set_handles(array<void*, 3> const& handles) noexcept -> void {
    ::SetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE, handles[0]);
    ::SetStdHandle(STD_ERROR_HANDLE, handles[1]);
    ::SetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE, handles[2]);
  }

  auto set_handles(array<std::FILE*, 3> const& handles) noexcept -> void {
    ::SetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE, handles[0]);
    ::SetStdHandle(STD_ERROR_HANDLE, handles[1]);
    ::SetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE, handles[2]);
  }
}

namespace winapi
{
  ConsoleHost::ConsoleHost(Mode mode) noexcept(false)
    : m_attached(false)
    , m_handles({nullptr, nullptr, nullptr})
    , m_original_handles(::get_handles())
  {
    try {
      ::try_alloc();
    } catch(windows_exception const&) {
      try {
        ::try_free();
        ::try_alloc();
      } catch(windows_exception const& e) {
        throw e;
      }
    }

    if(bool(mode & Mode::Stdout))
      ::freopen_s(&this->m_handles[0], "CONOUT$", "w", stdout);
    if(bool(mode & Mode::Stderr))
      ::freopen_s(&this->m_handles[1], "CONOUT$", "w", stderr);
    if(bool(mode & Mode::Stdin))
      ::freopen_s(&this->m_handles[2], "CONIN$", "r", stdin);

    ::set_handles(this->m_handles);
    std::cout.clear();
    std::clog.clear();
    std::cerr.clear();
    std::cin.clear();
    this->m_attached = true;
  }

  auto ConsoleHost::free() noexcept -> void {
    if(not ::try_free())
      ::MessageBoxW(nullptr, L"Failed to free the console!", nullptr, MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);
  }

  ConsoleHost::~ConsoleHost() noexcept {
    for(auto& h : this->m_handles)
      if(h)
        ::fclose(h);
    ConsoleHost::free();
    ::set_handles(this->m_original_handles);
  }

  /// other unrelated functions ... 
}

So, when I'm trying to allocate console, it works, but when or after destructor is called, stange assertion happens:
Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Library
Debug assertion failed!
Program: ...
File: minkernel\crts\ucrt\src\appcrt\lowio\isatty.cpp
Line: 17
Expression: (fh >= 0 && (unsigned)fn < (unsigned)_nhandle)

If I comment out ::fclose calls, test just terminates.
Test code:
using namespace std;

TEST(ConsoleAPI, ConsoleHost)
{
  // todo: this test doesn't work
  #if 1
  auto host = winapi::ConsoleHost(winapi::ConsoleHost::Mode::All);
  EXPECT_TRUE(host.is_attached());
  cout << "Test is ok" << endl;
  cin.get();
  #endif
  GTEST_SUCCEED();
}

If somebody encountered this before please share your knowledge.
Tried removing fclose calls in destuctor - test terminates without any stacktrace
Tried removing destructor at all - same as above.

Changing the global environment for local debugging purposes doesn't sound like a tractable approach. Consider using a less intrusive approach (e.g., OutputDebugStringW(), ETW, or the CRT's diagnostics support such as _CrtSetReportMode()).

I recommend reading the documentation for GetStdHandle.  In particular, the part on handle disposal.

::SetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE, handles[0]); - SetStdHandle expects a kernel handle, but you're passing a FILE*.
